# Android phonegap app - black blank screen issue

Tags: android, cordova

I have built a few Android phonegap applications using Eclipse but when I run those applications on device (mobile/emulator):

1. It will display a blank black screen at the initial
2. It will display a black blank screen for few seconds before navigating to another page.

Answer (score 1):

I've same problem previously. I solved by turn `android:hardwareAccelerated` to `false` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade to PhoneGap 1.3 the black screen between pages has been removed. We used to load each page in it's own activity but that is no longer the case.